# How change file permissions (chmod) via FTP by ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, chmod

I have some issue with changing CHMODs via FTP by ruby.

Sample of code:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.example.com')
ftp.login(ENV['FTP_USER'], ENV['FTP_PASS'])
ftp.chdir('/import')
ftp.mkdir(file_name)
ftp.chdir(file_name)
ftp.put(File.open(xml_file))
ftp.put(File.open(csv_file))
ftp.quit
```

I create a new directory and I upload two files into it. I must change CHMODs of new dir and files becouse other user can't remove it. I found something like that:

```
ftp.sendcmd("SITE CHMOD 777 filename")
```

but return this:

```
Net::FTPPermError: 502 SITE: Command not implemented.
```

Maybe someone knows how do that it?

Comment: did you try with `0777`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with `0777`.

Comment: Did you try just `ftp.sendcmd("SITE CHMOD 0777 #{filename}")`

Comment: Yes :) above code just a sample. In this case issue is in `SITE` command

Comment: The above .sendcmd() actually worked for me on a FTP host. So I assume it may be up to whether the FTP in use by that FTP host supports that command; even 0777 worked fine.